# Disable the zooming keyboard shortcuts in RStudio

Tags: r, editor, rstudio

RStudio provides the option to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in on the whole workspace and I often hit that combination by accident, when I would like to execute selected code with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is wasting time and I need to zoom out again afterwards.
So I would like to know if there's the possibility to disable these keybindings. These keyboard shortcuts are not available to edit under `Tools - Modify Keyboard Shortcuts`.
Rstudio version 1.1.456.

Comment: it is not possible at the moment, there is a github request [link](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1683) to fix this. Also check this forum [post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115009323688--Bugs-Shortcut-to-reset-the-editor-font-cannot-be-changed-or-disabled) where it gets confirmed. The github issue comes from this post. Rstudio doesn't support it by default.

Comment: Thanks, subscribed to the github issue. Should I keep this open for future references and especially to provide a solution if it's fixed upstream.

Comment: There's "Zoom in" in Tools - Modify Keyboard Shortcuts. That doesn't work ?

Comment: I don't have a Shortcut defined there, but the zooming still is happening, so I think this might be something different.